# Why does Twitter Bootstrap let me have more than 12 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a container that has 2 divs within it: `span9` and `span3`. Inside my `span9` div, I would expect to be limited to only 9 columns. However, unless I set the div within the `span9` to be a `span12`, it leaves 3 extra blank columns!

Why on earth would this happen? To me, "span9" should mean that I have 9 columns available. I don't see anything at all that I am using that would cause that content to be allowed to reset to 12 columns in the grid. Makes zero sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to the comment from @firtive, the code for nested columns is different for default responsive (non-fluid) grids or for fluid grids.

With the default grid, use **class="row"** and the number of nested columns in your case should indeed total 9 (the number of columns of its parent). This is because the columns have a fixed width.

With fluid grids, use **class="row-fluid"** and the number of nested columns should add up to 12. This is because the column widths vary, based on a percentage of the width of their parent.

Source [Bootstrap Docs](http://bit.ly/ZcZ2lw)

See examples below.

Hope this helps

**Default non-fluid example** [see this live](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/gBhjh/)

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="span9">

  <div class="row"> <!-- start nested row -->  

    <div class="span6">nested col</div>
    <div class="span3">nested col</div>  

  </div>           <!-- end nested row -->

</div> <!-- end span 9 parent  -->

<div class="span3">
span 3
</div>

</div> <!-- end row -->
```

**Fluid Grid Example**  [see this live](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/Y33XL/)

```
<div class="row-fluid">

  <div class="span9">

    <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- start nested fluid row -->  

      <div class="span6">nested col</div>
      <div class="span6">nested col</div>  

    </div>                 <!-- end nested fluid row -->

  </div> <!-- end span 9 parent -->

  <div class="span3">span 3</div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that this doesn't apply to Bootstrap 3 because you can mix and match column classes, so the number in the class names don't have to add up to 12. For example, here's the code for the "Mixed: mobile and desktop" example on their [sample grid page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">...</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the concept of trying to add up columns to equal 12 doesn't even make sense with Bootstrap 3. If you look inside bootstrap.css then you'll see that the column classes are simply percentages relative to the container div, e.g.:

```
.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

In this case, if the container's width is 1170px, then each `col-sm-6` div would have a width equal to 50% of 1170px (let's ignore the row's -15px side margins for simplicity's sake) regardless of how many columns are in that row. If there are more columns than could fit inside the container, then the columns would automatically wrap. If some of your columns are super tall, then you would want to use `<div class="clearfix"></div>` with a combination of the `visible-*` or `hidden-*` classes to ensure consistent row heights.

Reference: [Boostrap 3 Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: I'm so confused!  I thought the goal was to add up to 12, even in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @10basetom - nice explanation. it's a common misconception that the rows must add up to 12.

Comment: @Skelly thanks :). I agree with others that Bootstrap can be counter-intuitive in some cases, especially when it's your first project. For those who just can't stand the way Bootstrap does things, then you may also consider [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html) -- these guys are trying to make class semantics as close to English as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think in fractions: `span1` doesn't mean one column, it means 1/12 columns, while `span12` means 12/12 columns. `Span12` means a single column within the containing element that can be subdivided 12 times if necessary.

So if you wanted two columns you'd put two divs with `<div class="span6">`.