# Bootstrap 3: Please explain rules for adding up column numbers per row. (Apparently "up to 12" is not the answer!)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't find on the official [Bootstrap 3 Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) the rules for adding up column values per row.  It clearly states "# of columns" is 12 and the first set of examples all add up to 12.  Good.

But, then later the "Example: Mobile and desktop" example breaks that convention: .col-xs-12 and .col-xs-6 adds up to 18 and the page offers no explanation.

Can someone answer in plain English a set of rules for how to go about choosing what each column values should add up to, for non-nested situations?

Another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129715/why-does-twitter-bootstrap-let-me-have-more-than-12-columns) touched on this by stating "because you can mix and match column classes, ... don't have to add up to 12" but didn't explain the big picture rules for how one goes about thinking about what they should add up to and why.